# scala: value not a member of a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I read in a csv file to a DataFrame through scala. Then I got the following error when I tried to do filtering on a field:

```
val data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3n://myPath/myData.csv.bz2")
val newData = data.filter(data.Name != null)
```

Then I got the error below:

```
error: value Name is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       val newData = data.filter(data.Name != null)
```

Did I do anything wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataFrameNaFuctions for this

```
data.na.drop(Seq("Name"))
```

You can't access a column using the syntax **dataframe.fieldname** in scala spark.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data("Name")`. `DataFrames` don't get named accessor methods added to them for your fields.